# cosmos-sdk multimsg partial failure

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk

We're building a Cosmos SDK chain but we're seeing some odd behaviour when sending a multimsg transaction, for example:

```
I[2021-01-31|05:46:05.271] Executed block                               module=state height=1657 validTxs=3 invalidTxs=1
```

When we query the txhash for this particular transaction, there's no indication of any issues (raw_log contains no error messages, for example). Is there another way in which we can query the chain to figure out why 1 of the transactions was invalid/failed?